# What static-analysis tool can detect unsafe concurrent write in java

Tags: java, static-analysis, pmd, spotbugs

```
ArrayList<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(1, 20)
         .parallel()
         .forEach(objects::add);
Collections.sort(objects);
System.out.println(objects);
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

7 and 8 are missing because ArrayList is not thread safe.

Comment: I have never used it, but it looks like [Threadsafe by Contemplate](http://www.contemplateltd.com/) might do the job. A couple of things to note though: [1] It is not free, although you can get a free trial. [2] It doesn't seem to have been updated since Java 8, and the most recent release was in 2015.

Comment: I've tried it. It is quite useless comparing to pmd and spotbugs rules. it also fails to work with jdk 11